# How does Allah repeat creation?

Tags: quran, tafseer, creation

What does Allah mean when He says:

> Have they not considered how Allāh begins creation and then repeats it? Indeed that, for Allāh, is easy. (29:19)

I understand that He originated creation. But what is meant by,

> "and then repeats it"?

How have scholars interpreted this?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the translation you're using is Sahih International and it seems to be causing you confusion. You should look at other translations as well to get a more holistic understanding of the ayah if you're confused.

Here are some other translations for [Quran 29:19](https://quran.com/29?startingVerse=19):

> Have they not seen how Allah originates the creation then resurrects it? That is certainly easy for Allah.
>
> <sup>The Clear Quran translated by Dr. Mustafa Khattab</sup>
>
> Have they not considered how God originates creation, then brings
> it back? Truly that is easy for God.
>
> <sup>[The Study Quran](https://ia904603.us.archive.org/25/items/the-study-quran_202111/The%20Study%20Quran.pdf)</sup>

**Explanation of Quran 29:19**

This verse is one of many instances in which the Quran refers to God’s
Ability to “originate creation” as an argument for His Ability to resurrect, both
of which are said to be easy for God, as in 30:27: He it is Who originates
creation, then brings it back, and that is most easy for Him (see also 10:34;
27:64; 64:7; 10:4c; 30:11c).

Source: [The Study Quran PDF](https://ia904603.us.archive.org/25/items/the-study-quran_202111/The%20Study%20Quran.pdf) p. 2199

Answer (score 0):

God's creation is both initial and persisting.

God has created the world. The image of this initial creation, the creation in 6 days (or, 7, also counting the "day of rest" from the Torah account), is revealed in the Quran and in the Torah. We now know from our research that this is an image, not a report. The initial creation comprised the laws of physics, matter, and energy. In the image, this is the first day, which is many billion years.

Then the All evolved. God's creation continued. Each new thing came out of an existing thing, and still, it was created. These are the five following days in the image.

We are living after the last of those 6 (7) "days". Still, everything evolves, new living beings are born, and die, and the world continues to change. God's creation is continuous.

Reading the verse cited wth the next one:

> Have they not seen how God originates creation, then brings it back again? Surely that is an easy matter for God. Say: Journey in the land, then behold how He originated creation; then God causes the second growth to grow; God is powerful over everything.

we see this explained in th Quran.

God is with us. His creation continues, according to and coming forth from what He created before. The verse admonishes to be aware of this presence of God, the Creator.

Comment: God resting on the 7th day according to the Torah must be a fabricated addition since Allah doesn't get tired. It says in [Quran 2:255], "Neither drowsiness overtakes Him nor sleep"

Also, the Quran mentions that the Bible/Torah have been tampered with and distorted in Quran 2:75 and 2:79

Comment: 2:75-79 need not refer to the Torah. There are many writings, called "pseudoepigrapha" which were written under the name of a real prophet but fabricated. Those have been discarded also by Jewish and Christian scholars. The common Jewish interpretation of the seventh day is that God created the day of rest. We need not follow this interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

According to interpretations, it means to make alive and dead.
[ref](https://quran.anhar.ir/tafsir-14005.htm)

And they did not see how Allah begins the creation and then restores it. Indeed, this is easy for Allah." 19
Have they not seen how God starts creation, then brings it back? Of course, this is easy for God.

Points:

- In these two verses, three common principles among religions are mentioned:

A: Monotheism. "Allah's creation began"

B: Prophecy. "And we are on the Messenger of God except for the speech"

C: Resurrection "Thumamma Yoedeh"

Messages:

1- All the prophets had opponents. We should not be afraid of the opposition of the enemies.

The lie of the nation...

2- Historical events are similar and repeatable. "A nation before you"

3- Familiarity with history is a kind of consolation for humans. "The lies of nations before you"

4- The denial of the opponents should not hinder the promotion. And we are upon the Prophet...

5- People are free to choose their beliefs and the Prophet cannot force them. وَ إِنْ تقَدِِّبوا... We are on the Messenger of God except for the eloquent speaker. I told you what is the condition of eloquence.

6- Guidance and advertising must be clear and expressive. "Al-Balagh Al-Mubein"

7- By asking questions, let's wake up the nature of the ignorant. A and why...

8- Islam is a religion of thought and has invited all people to think.

A and why...

9- The world of creation is the manifestation of God's power in creating life and death of phenomena. "Allah begins creation and then restores it"

10- Creation is accidental and unstable, and finally they return to God.

"Allah begins creation and then restores it"

11- Belief in the origin is the reason for believing in the resurrection and ignorance of God's power is the reason for denying the resurrection. "Allah begins creation and then restores it"

12- Creating, dying and reviving is God's permanent work. "Allah began the creation and then it returns" (the present participle is a sign of continuity and durability.)

13- Initial creation and re-creation in the resurrection is easy for God, it only requires one will. "This is easy for Allah

Comment: This is rather a hint than an answer: A link to a tafsir may be helpful, but links tend to be broken sooner or later, and your link is about the whole surah; thus, a short summary is necessary to make it a valuable answer. It is further helpful if the original is not in English; your explanation will be particularly helpful because using Google translate, some contents may become awefully wrong. I have added the Google translate. Please make your point out of it.